# Python decorator as a staticmethod

Tags: python, decorator, static-methods

I'm trying to write a python class which uses a decorator function that needs information of the instance state. This is working as intended, but if I explicitly make the decorator a staticmetod, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tford.py", line 1, in <module>
    class TFord(object):
  File "tford.py", line 14, in TFord
    @ensure_black
TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

Why?

Here is the code:

```
class TFord(object):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    @staticmethod
    def ensure_black(func):
        def _aux(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.color == 'black':
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return None
        return _aux

    @ensure_black
    def get():
        return 'Here is your shiny new T-Ford'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ford_red = TFord('red')
    ford_black = TFord('black')

    print ford_red.get()
    print ford_black.get()
```

And if I just remove the line `@staticmethod`, everything works, but I do not understand why. Shouldn't it need `self` as a first argument?

Comment: Why do you think you need a `@staticmethod`? It seems clear that you don't understand what that means.  Static methods are not bound to an instance of an object, so they have no `self` argument (and no access to instance variables).

Comment: @Nick: The decorator `ensure_black` doesn't need an access to `self`.  It only needs to access `func`.

Comment: @Sven: Good point - I was thrown by the face that `def get()` also wasn't using `self`, so was confused as to how `_aux` could be.

Comment: Could you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260036/is-my-in-class-decorator-not-pythonic-enough-or-pycharm-not-smart-enough-in-lint/51260639?noredirect=1#comment89499456_51260639 and post how you made it to work without the constructor?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is not how `staticmethod` is supposed to be used.  `staticmethod` objects are [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html) that return the wrapped object, so they only work when accessed as `classname.staticmethodname`.  Example

```
class A(object):
    @staticmethod
    def f():
        pass
print A.f
print A.__dict__["f"]
```

prints

```
<function f at 0x8af45dc>
<staticmethod object at 0x8aa6a94>
```

Inside the scope of `A`, you would always get the latter object, which is not callable.

I'd strongly recommend to move the decorator to the module scope -- it does not seem to belong inside the class.  If you want to keep it inside the class, don't make it a `staticmethod`, but rather simply `del` it at the end of the class body -- it's not meant to be used from outside the class in this case.

Comment: Ok, it is just that ensure_black has zero uses outside this class. I'm happy to just remove the `@staticmethod`, I would just like to know why it works. Without that the staticmethod decorator, is ensure_black still a static method?

Comment: @wkz: No, it's just a plain Python function defined inside the scope of the class `TFord`.  Functions inside the class scope aren't special in anyway.  They will only be treated specially when accessed via an instance like in `ford_black.get`.  This expression won't simply return the function `get()` as defined inside the class scope but rather a "bound method wrapper" that makes sure the correct instance is passed as `self` parameter when the function is called -- see the above link and the example.  The example circumvents the special treatment by using `A.__dict__["f"]`.

Comment: marnach: Thank you! That was the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @SvenMarnach I was doing exactly what OP was doing, so your answers very helpful, thank you.

Comment: Technically, staticmethod objects do not **use** descriptors, they **are** descriptors, assuming the definition of "if any of `__get__`, ... is implemented" stands.

Comment: I'm facing a scenario where I want the descriptor to be inside the class, because I want to use the class as a mixin :-/

Comment: I came up with the solution to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59481429/7837628

Answer (score 11):

Python classes are created at runtime, after evaluating the contents of the class declaration. The class is evaluated by assigned all declared variables and functions to a special dictionary and using that dictionary to call `type.__new__` (see [customizing class creation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation)).

So,

```
class A(B):
    c = 1
```

is equivalent to:

```
A = type.__new__("A", (B,), {"c": 1})
```

When you annotate a method with @staticmethod, there is some special magic that happens AFTER the class is created with `type.__new__`. Inside class declaration scope, the @staticmethod function is just an instance of a staticmethod object, which you can't call. The decorator probably should just be declared above the class definition in the same module OR in a separate "decorate" module (depends on how many decorators you have). In general decorators should be declared outside of a class. One notable exception is the property class (see [properties](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property)).  In your case having the decorator inside a class declaration might make sense if you had something like a color class:

```
class Color(object):

    def ___init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

     def ensure_same_color(f):
         ...

black = Color("black")

class TFord(object):
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    @black.ensure_same_color
    def get():
        return 'Here is your shiny new T-Ford'
```

Answer (score 4):

**Solution** does exist!

Problem is that Static method that is trying to be used as decorator is in fact staticmethod object and is not callable.

**Solution**: staticmethod object has method `__get__` which takes any argument and returns real method: [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) Python 3.5 and up:

```
class StaticMethod(object):
    "Emulate PyStaticMethod_Type() in Objects/funcobject.c"

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return self.f
```

Min solution I came with is:

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.n =  2

    @staticmethod
    def _returnBaseAndResult(func):
        from functools import wraps
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            self = args[0]
            response = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return self.n, response
        return wrapper

    @_returnBaseAndResult.__get__('this can be anything')
    def square(self):
        return self.n**2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    print(a.square())
```

Will print (2, 4)

Answer (score -1):

`ensure_black` is returning a `_aux` method that isn't decorated by `@staticmethod`

You can return a non-static method to a static_method

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod

Comment: No, that has nothing to do with it.

Comment: of course it has.. if he is using @staticmethod self is not available in his method context.. (although his code do not work because of that)