# how to use decorator in a class

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I know there is similar question, but my scenario is somehow different: refer to codes:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, log_location)
        self.logs = logging(log_location) # create log object by the log_location, this object should be used by the decorator fucntion

    def record_log(log_object): 
        """ this is the decorator function
        """
        def deco(func):
            def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
                rs = func()

                # use log object to record log
                if rs:
                    log_object.record('success')
                else:
                    log_object.record('fail')

            return wrap
        return deco

   @record_log(self.logs) 
   def test(self):
       rs = do_some_thing
       if rs:
            return True
       return False

def main():
    my_class = MyClass()
    my_class.test()
```

But, there is an error like this:

```
@record_log(self.logs)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Hos should I use the instance attribute self.logs in a decorator function in such scenario like this??

Thanks very much!

Comment: then, it will tell me that name'logs' is not defined.

Comment: then how should I pass self.logs to it?

Comment: using `@decorator` is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several objections about your code:

1. `deco()` is redundant. You can directly return `wrap` from `record_log()`.
2. If you only plan to decorate `MyClass`'s methods, then there is no point in passing `log_object` to the decorator, as `self.logs` will always be used. Otherwise, consider moving the decorator to module level, as already suggested by others.
3. The decorated method's return value is currently lost.
4. The call to the decorated function does not pass `self` to it.

The proper code would therefore be:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, log_location):
        self.logs = logging(log_location)

    def record_log(func):
        """ this is the decorator function
        """
        def wrap(self):
            rs = func(self)
            # use log object to record log
            if rs:
                print 1
                self.logs.record('success')
            else:
                print 2
                self.logs.record('fail')
            return rs
        return wrap

    @record_log
    def test(self):
       rs = do_some_thing
       if rs:
            return True
       return False
```

Comment: Nice... but I think you should use `*args, **kwargs` as parameters and get `self` from `args[0]`, so the decorator is applicable to other methods of the class.

Comment: Thanks Vadim for the detailed comments about the code and thanks for the solution.

Thanks @tobias_k also very much, but this solution is better for my scenario.

thanks all the guys for the help!!!

Comment: Don't forget to keep @tobias_k 's comments in mind as well :)

Comment: Hi @VadimLanda, another 2 questions:

1. there is no 'self' parameter for function 'rocord_log', is it a static method? If not, what's the difference between it and a static method wrapped by 'staticmethod' ?
2. as you mentioned in the 3rd point, "The decorated method's return value is currently lost", why there must be return value in a decorator?

Comment: 1. Technically, `record_log` is a static method, however, you cannot use `@staticmethod` with that - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412146/python-decorator-as-a-staticmethod for details. 2. As decorators are wrappers around functions, then in most cases, you'll still want to know the original function's result. Of course, you may discard that in the decorator if you don't care about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can not pass a reference to `self` or any attribute of `self` at this point. The `@record_log` line is executed (the method is decorated) before the code in `main` is executed, i.e. before any instance of `MyClass` is created at all -- in fact, even before the definition of `MyClass` has been completed! But remember that

```
@record_log(self.logs) 
def test(self, n):
```

is actually just syntactic sugar for

```
test = record_log(self.logs)(test)
```

So one way to work around your problem would be to redefine `test` in your `__init__`, i.e.

```
def __init__(self, log_location)
    self.logs = logging(log_location)
    self.test = record_log(self.logs)(self.test)
```

Also note that your decorator is not passing any parameters to `func` and not returning the results. Also, it should probably be defined on module level (before the class).

```
def record_log(log_object): 
    def deco(func):
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            rs = func(*args, **kwargs)   # pass parameters
            if rs:
                log_object.record('success')
            else:
                log_object.record('fail')
            return rs   # return result
        return wrap
    return deco
```

Comment: Hi tobias_k, thanks for your help. It works now, even though a little ugly. And another question is: as  

@record_log(self.logs)
def test(self, n):

is actually just syntactic sugar for

test = record_log(self.logs)(test)

why one work, while the other doesn't???

Comment: @Spybdai Because, as I said, the `@record_log` statement is executed _before_ the class is even fully created, while the `self.test = ...` is executed when an instance of the class is being created.