# Why are python static/class method not callable?

Tags: python, oop, methods

Why are python instance methods callable, but static methods and class methods not callable?

I did the following:

```
class Test():
    class_var = 42

    @classmethod 
    def class_method(cls):
        pass 

    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        pass

    def instance_method(self):
        pass 

for attr, val in vars(Test).items():
    if not attr.startswith("__"):
        print (attr, "is %s callable" % ("" if callable(val) else "NOT"))
```

The result is:

```
static_method is NOT callable
instance_method is  callable
class_method is NOT callable
class_var is NOT callable
```

Technically this may be because instance method object might have a particular attribute (not) set in a particular way (possibly `__call__`). Why such asymmetry, or what purpose does it serve?

I came across this while learning python inspection tools.

**Additional remarks from comments:**

*The SO answer linked in the comments says that the static/class methods are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) , which are not callable. Now I am curious, why are descriptors made not callable, since descriptors are class with particular attributes (one of `__get__`, `__set__`, `__del___`) defined.*

Comment: taks a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412146/python-decorator-as-a-staticmethod

Comment: @MK. The linked answer says the static/class methods are descriptors so they are not callable. Why are decriptors made not callable?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python

Comment: The SO answer you point to actually claims they "use" descriptors. But according to definition, they indeed *are* descriptors themselves (implement `__get__`).

Comment: What makes you think descriptors "are class"? Are you saying a descriptor is a class object, or instance of some class?

Comment: Also, please clarify what do you mean by "callable". Even the Python docs are slightly contradictory on the topic...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Why are descriptors not callable?** Basically because they don't need to be. Not every descriptor represents a callable either.

As you correctly note, the descriptor protocol consists of `__get__`, `__set__` and `__del__`. Note no `__call__`, that's the technical reason why it's not callable. The actual callable is the return value of your `static_method.__get__(...)`.

As for the philosophical reason, let's look at the class. The contents of the `__dict__`, or in your case results of `vars()`, are basically `locals()` of the `class` block. If you `def`ine a function, it gets dumped as a plain function. If you use a decorator, such as `@staticmethod`, it's equivalent to something like:

```
def _this_is_not_stored_anywhere():
    pass
static_method = staticmethod(_this_is_not_stored_anywhere)
```

I.e., `static_method` is assigned a return value of the `staticmethod()` function.

Now, function objects actually implement the descriptor protocol - every function has a `__get__` method on it. This is where the special `self` and the bound-method behavior comes from. See:

```
def xyz(what):
    print(what)

repr(xyz)  # '<function xyz at 0x7f8f924bdea0>'
repr(xyz.__get__("hello"))  # "<bound method str.xyz of 'hello'>"
xyz.__get__("hello")()  # "hello"
```

Because of how the class calls `__get__`, your `test.instance_method` binds to the instance and gets it pre-filled as it first argument.

But the whole point of `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` is that they do something special to avoid the default "bound method" behavior! So they can't return a plain function. Instead they return a descriptor object with a custom `__get__` implementation.

Of course, you *could* put a `__call__` method on this descriptor object, but why? It's  code that you don't need in practice; you can almost never touch the descriptor object itself. If you do (in code similar to yours), you still need special handling for descriptors, because a general descriptor doesn't have to be(have like a) callable - properties are descriptors too. So you don't want `__call__` in the descriptor protocol. So if a third party "forgets" to implement `__call__` on something you consider a "callable", your code will miss it.

Also, the object is a descriptor, not a function. Putting a `__call__` method on it would be masking its true nature :) I mean, it's not *wrong* per se, it's just ... something that you should never need for anything.

BTW, in case of classmethod/staticmethod, you can get back the original function from their `__func__` attribute.