# In python, can I access a method in class scope (but not in function scope)

Tags: python

For better encapsulation, I want to decorate instance methods with methods inside the same class.

```
class SomeClass(object):

    @staticmethod
    def some_decorator(func):
        def wrapped(self):
            print 'hello'
            return func(self)
        return wrapped

    @some_decorator
    def do(self):
        print 'world'

x = SomeClass()
x.do()
```

However, this piece of code raises `TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable`

Now I make a workaround by defining a class and overload its **new** method to simulate a function, but it's eventually a class, not a function.

So can I access my functions inside the class scope?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python decorator as a staticmethod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412146/python-decorator-as-a-staticmethod)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get rid of that `@staticmethod` line. You want `some_decorator` to behave like a plain function, not like some kind of method.

The decorator is called when the class definition is being executed, before the class object itself exists. The normal method definitions inside a class are actually just plain old functions, they become methods dynamically each time they are called as attributes of the class instance (which turns them into bound methods). But while the class object itself is being built you can treat them as plain functions.

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def some_decorator(func):
        def wrapped(self):
            print 'hello'
            return func(self)
        return wrapped

    @some_decorator
    def do(self):
        print 'world'

x = SomeClass()
x.do()
```

**output**

```
hello
world
```

BTW, you have an error in your decorator: it's returning `wrapped()` instead of `wrapped`.

---

As chepner mentions in the comments we can delete `some_decorator` so that it doesn't take up space in the class object after we've finished using it in the class definition. (If we accidentally try to call it we'll get an error). We *could* do `del SomeClass.some_decorator` after the class definition, but it's also perfectly valid to put a `del` statement inside the class definition:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def some_decorator(func):
        def wrapped(self):
            print 'hello'
            return func(self)
        return wrapped

    @some_decorator
    def do(self):
        print 'world'

    del some_decorator
```

Comment: You can add `del some_decorator` to the end of the class definition if you don't want to clutter your class's namespace. You don't need it anymore after `do` is defined.

Comment: @chepner Good point. I originally didn't bother, since it's pretty hard to call it outside the class definition without raising `TypeError`, but I guess it's cleaner to get rid of it.